# Hack `kur -v data mnist.yml` for a simpler overview of data on provider?

Tags: python, deep-learning

**The problem**

When I run `kur -v data mnist.yml`, kur prints out a batch of samples, which is so long that you can see or take a long time to scroll to the beginning for log messages.

Then I store the log output in a file with `kur -v data mnist.yml 2>&1 | tee my.txt`, and now I can paste the log messages below

```
[1;37m[INFO 2017-03-25 16:18:09,717 kur.kurfile:709][0m Parsing source: mnist.yml, included by top-level.[0m
[1;37m[INFO 2017-03-25 16:18:09,724 kur.kurfile:709][0m Parsing source: mnist-defaults.yml, included by mnist.yml.[0m
[1;37m[INFO 2017-03-25 16:18:09,733 kur.kurfile:84][0m Parsing Kurfile...[0m
[1;37m[INFO 2017-03-25 16:18:09,749 kur.__main__:144][0m Preparing data sources for: train[0m
Entry 1/32:
  images: [[[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
...
...
```

The problem with this output is that it is not exactly what I want. I normally want two things from a data overview: 
1. shape of provided data
2. a sample printed out

Current `kur -v data mnist.yml` just prints out total 32 samples in a batch. To be fair, `kur -vv data mnist.yml` do tell us the number of samples in a batch. That's it.

**Challenge**

How to make `kur -v data mnist.yml` to print out:

1. shape of provided data
2. a sample printed out

Like the following:

```
[INFO 2017-03-25 14:31:14,318 kur.kurfile:760] Parsing source: mnist.yml, included by top-level.
[INFO 2017-03-25 14:31:14,324 kur.kurfile:760] Parsing source: mnist-defaults.yml, included by mnist.yml.
[INFO 2017-03-25 14:31:14,334 kur.kurfile:113] Parsing Kurfile...
[INFO 2017-03-25 14:31:15,465 kur.__main__:290] A single batch consists of: {'labels': (32, 10), 'images': (32, 28, 28, 1)}
[INFO 2017-03-25 14:31:15,465 kur.__main__:294] There are total 32 samples in a single batch.
[INFO 2017-03-25 14:31:15,466 kur.__main__:295] Let's have a look a single sample
Entry 1/32:
  images: [[[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.86933935]
  [ 0.61835897]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.37130019]
  [ 0.12031978]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]

 [[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]]]
  labels: [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to hack a little of [`__main__.py`](https://github.com/EmbraceLife/kur_hack/blob/master/__main__.py)

Replace [the original code](https://hyp.is/d_gTsBE2Eeer-5cLkV0AMg/github.com/deepgram/kur/blob/master/kur/__main__.py):

```
num_entries = len(batch[keys[0]])
for entry in range(num_entries):
    print('Entry {}/{}:'.format(entry+1, num_entries))
    for k in keys:
        print('  {}: {}'.format(k, batch[k][entry]))
```

With [this new code](https://hyp.is/D4Mx1BE2EeecYWvtHyX5tw/github.com/EmbraceLife/kur_hack/blob/master/__main__.py):

```
#### What is the shape of each key's values
batch_shape = {}
for k in keys:
    batch_shape[k] = batch[k].shape
logger.info("A single batch consists of: %s", batch_shape)

### count inside the first element of batch dictionary, assign to num_entries
num_entries = len(batch[keys[0]])
logger.info("There are total %s samples in a single batch.", num_entries)
logger.info("Let's have a look a single sample")

### print out the whole batch, but one sample pair at a time, each sample pair like (key1:value, key2: value)
# for entry in range(0, num_entries)
### Here only print out the first and last sample of a batch
# for entry in range(0, num_entries, num_entries-1):
for entry in range(1):
    ## print Entry entry_idx/total_entries
    print('Entry {}/{}:'.format(entry+1, num_entries))
    ## for every batch_key
    for k in keys:
        # print: batch_key: this batch's first item
        print('  {}: {}'.format(k, batch[k][entry]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to output a simpler view of data:

```
In [17]: !kur -v data --single mnist.yml
[INFO 2017-03-29 11:34:42,369 kur.kurfile:712] Parsing source: mnist.yml, included by top-level.
[INFO 2017-03-29 11:34:42,376 kur.kurfile:712] Parsing source: mnist-defaults.yml, included by mnist.yml.
[INFO 2017-03-29 11:34:42,386 kur.kurfile:85] Parsing Kurfile...
[INFO 2017-03-29 11:34:42,407 kur.__main__:147] Preparing data sources for: train
[INFO 2017-03-29 11:34:43,309 kur.__main__:186] We are training with 15 batches using 480 samples of data
[INFO 2017-03-29 11:34:43,309 kur.__main__:190] A single batch consists of: {'labels': (32, 10), 'images': (32, 28, 28, 1)}
Entry 1/32:
  images: [[[-0.13066062]
  [-0.13066062]
```